# java replace special characters to text

Tags: java, replace, special-characters

I have the following code which is changing the text I am inputting to UPPERCASE

```
if(WrtMsg.isDisplayable()== true); {
    //System.out.println(test.toString().toUpperCase());
        RecView.setText(test.toString().toUpperCase());
}
```

Now I want special characters like asterix (*) to be changes as text. Example `*` to `ATX` ... So the output will be displayed as `ATX`.

`WrtMsg` is the `jtextarea` of text input and `RecView` is the `jtextarea` where the output is showing.

Any help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered manually changing it in code? You could create a method like this:

```
private String charToText(String character) {
character = character.replace("*", "ATX")
// and so forth...
return character;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot for a sec. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `replaceAll` method of the `String` class. `something.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("*"), "ATX")`.

Comment: I think you mean `Pattern.quote(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(wrtMsg.getText().contains("*"))
{
    RecView.setText("ATX");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the replace method of the string object

```
test.toString().toUpperCase().replace("*", "ATX")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RecView.setText(wrtMsg.getText().replace("*", "ATX"));
```